# ReferenceError: field_2a is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have three input fields and i want to get there data when data is entered. **Though it works fine but still it shows this error in firebug.**

Hope there will be a better way to do this.

**ERROR showing in firbug :**

```
ReferenceError: field_2a is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

...ataString = 'field-1a='+ field_1a + '&field-2a=' + field_2a + '&field-4a=' + fie...
```

My script is as under :

```
<script>

        function getFielddata(field_id, field_value){
            if(field_value != ""){


                //alert(field_id+" "+field_value);
                if(field_id == "field-1a"){

                    if(field_value){
                        field_1a = field_value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        field_1a = "";  
                    }
                }

                else if(field_id == "field-2a"){
                    if(field_value){
                        field_2a = field_value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        field_2a = "";  
                    }

                }

                else if(field_id == "field-4a"){
                    if(field_value){
                        field_4a = field_value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        field_4a = "";  
                    }
                }

                var dataString = 'field-1a='+ field_1a + '&field-2a=' + field_2a + '&field-4a=' + field_4a;
                //alert(dataString); return false;
                $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: 'get_query.php',
                   data: dataString,
                   success: function(data) {
                    //$("#SuburbDiv").html(data);
                    alert("data inserted successfully");
                   }
                  });

            }
        }

    </script>
```

and i am saving it onChange event like this :

```
<input type="text" id="field-2a" onChange="getFielddata(this.id, this.value)"/>
```

and Help ???

**Note : There is no submit button**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are initializing the `field-#a` inside the if statements that never get executed, then you try to access them. I also have a feeling that these variables have to be local to the function. Try this:

```
function getFielddata(field_id, field_value){
        if(field_value != ""){
            var field_1a = "",
                field_2a = "",
                field_4a = "";

            //alert(field_id+" "+field_value);
            if((field_id == "field-1a")){
                field_1a = field_value;
            }
            else if((field_id == "field-2a")){
                field_2a = field_value;
            }
            else if((field_id == "field-4a")){
                field_4a = field_value;
            }

            var dataString = 'field-1a='+ field_1a + '&field-2a=' + field_2a + '&field-4a=' + field_4a;
            //alert(dataString); return false;
            $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: 'get_query.php',
               data: dataString,
               success: function(data) {
                //$("#SuburbDiv").html(data);
                alert("data inserted successfully");
               }
              });

        }
    }
```

Comment: ! in this case data is posted for after every change, how would i restrict it to submit only when there is data for all the fields,
i am trying to apply checks of if(field_1a != "" && .....) so that it posts only when we have all the three fields data but it is still posting the data for even one field without waiting for others

Comment: I am not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve. The way I presented you the answer preserves the logic you had, of course there could be some enhancements, but it is doing the same thing you did without throwing an error you had.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are defining those variables in some other scope they have not been declared.

Use the var keyword to declare them at the top of your function.

```
var field_1a, field_2a, field_4a;
```

Comment: ! same is the case with this too, data is posted after every single field change, how would i restrict it to submit only when there is data for all the fields,
i am trying to apply checks of if(field_1a != "" && .....) so that it posts only when we have all the three fields data but it is still posting the data